# javascript RegExp word boundary issue

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code:

```
var boo = new RegExp("\\Bis\\B","gi");
var result = boo.exec("this AisA stackoverflow");
document.write(result);​
```

The result is: "is" but i want the function exec to return the whole match ie AisA using
the non-word boundary \B. I know i can use a pattern such as .+is.+ to return AisA but
i'm wondering how to do the same thing with a non-word boundary.

Comment: Don't use `new RegExp` with static strings; JavaScript has faster, better, and less error-prone literals. For example, yours could be written as `var boo = /\Bis\B/gi;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/.\Bis\B./
```

This will check for the non-boundary, and also take that character with the `.`.

Comment: That also matches "cisd" out of "abcisdefg".  Depending on what his application is, /\w*is\w*/ might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're after?

```
\S*\Bis\B\S*
```

Since the boundary doesn't match characters but only checks a condition you have to use something else to get the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Word boundaries are what is known as a zero-width match, meaning that they match a condition, not a character. For example, in the regex "\bw", "\b" tests that there is some whitespace either preceeding or following its location within the expression. It does not capture anything.

If you want to capture a word character, try using \w.

See: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/watch-out-for-zero-length-matches/

Answer (score 0):

To match a word containing 'is':

```
/\b\w*is\w*/gi
```

The last \b is not necessary because it's part of LA(\w*).